# Unexpected token 'react' when using react-moralis

Tags: node.js, reactjs, moralis

I was able to install the package for react-moralis without any issues. When trying to import from the package I receive an "unexpected token failed to compile" syntax error. The simple code is this

```
import { Moralis} from react-moralis
```

[image: Failed to compile error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in quotes like this:

```js
import { Moralis } from 'react-moralis'
```